# Logging an error and creating an error when the logging fails create a circular dependency between two projects

Tags: design, circular-dependency

As part of a program I am developing for practice purposes, I've created a namespace `Core` designed to contain the core code resources for the program to use. This namespace is in a Class Library project.

Two of the sub-namespaces in `Core` are `Core.Files` and `Core.Errors`. In `Core.Files` there is a `TxtFile` class that is responsible for input-output to .txt files. In `Core.Errors` there is an `Error` class which is responsible for managing a specific error. The class API allows you to manage an error in three ways:

1. Display the error to the user.
2. Record the error in a log file.
3. Perform both.

In the last two options, `Error` depends on `TxtFile` to record the error in the log file (using the `Write()` method).

The `Write()` method in `TxtFile` is built in such a way that if it fails to write text into the file, `Error` is instantiated. Since something is obviously not working in `Write()`, the error is displayed to the user but not logged in the file.

Everything works great. Over time, however, the two namespaces grew, and I thought it would be appropriate to create a separate project for each of them.

The problem is that since `Error` depends on`TxtFile` and `TxtFile` depends on`Error`, there is a circular dependency between the two projects, and it is impossible to add references between them.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052632/1925272) suggests that such a situation is an indication of bad design. How can I improve the design so that this problem does not occur? I want to preserve the structure of a single assembly per sub-namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not interested in redesigning the object model, the following (fairly common) change will get you going again.

1. Start a new class library called `Interfaces` or something similar.
2. In both of your existing projects, add a reference to `Interfaces`.
3. In the new library, define an interface `IError` and `ITxtFile` that match the methods and properties needed of both classes by both libraries.
4. Modify the two existing libraries so that `Error` and `TxtFile` implement the interfaces you just created.
5. Write factories for both `TxtFile` and `Error`.  They don't have to be fancy.
6. Modify the constructor for `Error` so that it takes a `TxtFileFactory` as a constructor argument.  Use the factory to create the `TxtFile` (instead of the `new` keyword).
7. Modify the constructor for `TxtFile` so that it takes a `ErrorFactory` as a constructor argument.  Use the factory to create the `Error` (instead of the `new` keyword).
8. Add `TxtFileFactory` and `ErrorFactory` to your dependency injection container.
9. Modify your code so you only work with the interfaces, not the concrete types.

Explanation: Neither project will depend on the other for object creation.  Instead, they will get their references from a factory that is injected.  Because the object graph is defined in the composition root, the need for circular dependency for object creation is eliminated, and because of the interfaces defined in the third library, there is no longer any circular interface dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am pretty new to design patterns, so I am not very familiar with dependency injection containers. Could you please modify your answer so a DIC is not required? Thanks again!

Comment: Could you help me, please? :)